# Moderncv underfull and academicons warning

Tags: warnings, academicons, underfull

The following minimal example gives an underfull bad box. When I uncomment the quote line, it somehow works. What is the problem? I don't understand the behavior. Is it possible to not use a quote and have no bad box at the same time?

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\name{John}{Smith}
%\quote{}  % uncomment to get rid of the underfull bad box

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \section{Education}
\end{document}
```

Additionally, I get the warning "academicons requires xetex/luatex to work. Using alternatives.". What should I do with that?

Comment: the obvious solution to the message you quote is to do what it says and use lualatex or xelatex instead of pdflatex.

Comment: Why? What is the need for such an effort in my minimal example? (Xelatex is slow.)

Comment: I think moderncv should first check if the user is indeed using academicons and then output the warning if necessary.

Comment: ignoring the message is also possible. It isn't clear what you are asking with "What should I do with that?"

Comment: When writing tex files I want to get rid of all warnings.

Comment: you can make a feaure request at their github, can not change the class here. Although the fonts need to be set up in the preamble but presumably you can't tell if the icons are used until the body of the document so i'm not sure how that would work, haven't looked at the code though,

Comment: @Thrash If you don't want to use XeTeX you can always use LuaLaTeX. That should even be faster for such documents.